# Geting HTTP 403 running a Spring app with AppEngine Plugin

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to run a very simple Spring with Google AppEngine.
I'm following [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/getting-started-with-google-app-engine-and-spring-boot-in-5-steps-2d0f8165c89) tutorial.

The app runs perfectly with normal mvn command. However, when I run `mvn appengine:run` the endpoint only returns HTTP 403.

[image]

This is the pom.xml configuration

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>HelloAppEngine</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>HelloAppEngine</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Everything else is identical to the tutorial.

Comment: Don't you use javax.servlet-api dependency?  "Google App Engine uses Jetty while default Spring Boot uses Tomcat." What about the plugins? Don't you use any plugins? You have only the provided code on your pom.xml ?

Comment: Did you maintain the static-files section in the appengine-web.xml file?